# Possible bug? "Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field" displays twice

Tags: civimail, issues, bug-reporting

Seems that **Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field** option has two identical copies in CiviMail Component Settings.

Also present on test server. https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this happened since 5.8.  I have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14852/files) for this issue. You can either apply [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14852.patch) or wait for 5.18 release.

> **Note:** Since this change involves update to settings file, you will
>   need to clear civicrm cache after applying patch.

Cheers

Pradeep